# Launchy: can't use a shorcut to create a new email for a specific person using Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, launchy

I have shortcuts for email sending. For example I open Launchy, type "new email Steeve" hit enter and window pop ups with Steeve's email address in "To" field.

Recently, my Office was upgraded to 2013 and it stopped working. The most problematic part is that if I open shortcut's folder in windows explorer and execute them, every shortcut does what it is supposed to do. If I launch them through command line, they work fine too.

**BUT when I try to launch them using Launchy, it just opens a new full outlook instance. Not a new email window, but the whole outlook.**

*Any ideas how to fix it? Looks like Launchy does some additional stuff compared to just executing shortcuts?*

Shortcut example: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\OUTLOOK.EXE" /c ipm.note /m email@email.co.uk

Comment: Similar issue here: http://superuser.com/questions/963031/how-do-i-set-up-a-shortcut-to-start-conemu-from-launchy-with-a-certain-task. Did your shortcut in the classic office world also contain a `/c`?

Comment: Seems like Launchy has an issue with whitespace in the paths when it comes to links: http://sourceforge.net/p/launchy/bugs/353/ My issue was solved by moving Console2 to a path without whitespace.

Comment: @eckes Yes, my shortcuts are totally the same as with the old outlook. Also, I can't move outlook to a folder without spaces :(

Answer (score 0):

I copied Outlook.exe to a new folder path without spaces, updated my shortcut with the "/c ipm.note" flags to point to that new exe location, and it did work. Unfortunately it takes a couple seconds to open - I think it's initializing a new instance of Outlook behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done works great.

Here's an alternative: using the Weby plugin,
use this as the URL:   mailto:%1

I named this emzz (to make it unique)

I type emzz (Tab) emailaddress

Boom, my default email client opens a new email to that person.

You can get very fancy with additional fields typed into Launchy.

This gives you subject and cc fields, then you'd have to do something like
mailto: %1 %2 %3
and type:
emzz (Tab) person@emailaddress.com (Tab) SAMPLEsubject (Tab) ccperson@emailaddress.com

The reference for the structure of the mailto: URL is here: https://developer.yoast.com/blog/guide-mailto-links/