# How do I set up a shortcut to start ConEmu from Launchy with a certain task?

Tags: conemu, console2, launchy

I'm migrating from Console2 to ConEmu (on Windows 7, if that matters).

With Console2, I could set up a shortcut and start a certain tab directly with this shortcut from Launchy. For example, when the `Git` tab should be opened, I created a shortcut with the name `git` and the target `C:\bin\Console2\Console2.exe -t Git`. The shortcut was indexed by Launchy and if I activated Launchy and typed `git`, the console was started with the Git tab open.

No problem so far.

---

Now, I migrate to ConEmu. I do the same. I set up a shortcut with the name `conemu-git` and the target `"C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu64.exe" /cmd {my-git-bash}`. Check whether the shortcut works and double click it: everything is fine.

**However**, when I now start Launchy and type `conemu-git`, the **default terminal** is started in ConEmu. Seems like the `/cmd {my-git-bash}`-part is completely ignored here.

Does anybody have an idea what is going wrong here?

---

**Edit:**
[Launchy: can't use a shorcut to create a new email for a specific person using Outlook 2013](https://superuser.com/questions/879844/launchy-cant-use-a-shorcut-to-create-a-new-email-for-a-specific-person-using-o) seems to be a very similar issue. While I'm migrating from Console2, Povilas in the linked question switched to a new office version. What we share: **the shortcut to be indexed contains a `/c` (`/cmd` here, plain `/c` there).** Maybe this helps solving this issue...

---

**Edit:**
http://sourceforge.net/p/launchy/bugs/353/ indicates that this an open issue of lauchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what is Launchy or what requirements it has while running commands (or even L.bugs?)

1. If ConEmu is started (isn't it?) than you may have configuration problems. Does your task exists in the started ConEmu instance tasks list?
2. Hardly probable, but Launchy may have problems with paths containing spaces. You've run Console from path without spaces.
3. Check arguments of started instance by ProcessExplorer. Launchy may break them somehow. Check what processes were actually started using ProcessMonitor.
4. You may use `-cmd` instead of `/cmd`, both mutations are supported. Try to put double quotes around task name.

Comment: Hardly believable but **2** is it. If I take the ConEmu64 folder and put it into `C:\bin\ `, the shortcut gets executed as requested!